# Python refer to range of letters of word in list

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I'm new in python and i want to ask if there is a way to refer to range of letters of a word in list e.g.(z is each word):

```
list_TFF[z] = list_TFF[z[0:1]] + list_TFF[z[3:5]]
```

This code gives error int object is not subscritable.

Comment: Could you show an exemple of `list_TFF` and `z`?

Comment: list_TFF is a list with big words and z it's each word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're subscripting the integer, when you want to subscript the respective elemnent.

What you probably want:

```
list_TFF[z] = list_TFF[z][0:1] + list_TFF[z][3:5]
```